# WKWebview won't load certain websites properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, https, wkwebview, app-transport-security

I need to load a wide assortment of website URLS (which come from a webservice) into a WKWebview.

Some websites, behave quite well, and load properly just by replacing "http" for "https" in the URL:

```
http://www.yahoo.com/news -> loads blank
**https://www.yahoo.com/news -> loads OK!!**

URLs without the https:// prefix will NOT load at all.

http://www.google.com -> blank 
**https://www.google.com -> Loads OK!!!**
http://www.bbc.co.uk/news (no .plist Exception) -> blank
https://www.bbc.co.uk/news (no .plist Exception) -> blank
http://www.bbc.co.uk/news (WITH .plist Exception) -> blank
https://www.bbc.co.uk/news (WITH .plist Exception) -> blank
```

(I pasted https://www.bbc.co.uk/news on MAC OS browser, and got redirected to https://www.bbc.co.uk/news, so I tried them as well:)

```
https://www.bbc.com/news (WITH .plist Exception) -> Images and text are loaded in a messy, unformatted, basic way.
http://www.bbc.com/news (WITH .plist Exception) -> Images and text are loaded in a messy, unformatted, basic way.
https://www.bbc.com/news (WITHOUT .plist Exception) -> blank
http://www.bbc.com/news (WITHOUT .plist Exception) -> blank
```

Other urls behave just like the BBC, or, Yahoo examples above.

This is the sort of exception I use on the .plist file.

This is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    CGRect wkFrame = _wios10container.frame;
    NSLog(@"WPVC - viewDidLoad, wkFrame: %@",NSStringFromCGRect(wkFrame));
    WKWebViewConfiguration *wkConfiguration = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
    _webviewIOS10 = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:_wios10container.frame configuration:wkConfiguration];
    _webviewIOS10.navigationDelegate = self;
    [_wios10container addSubview:_webviewIOS10];
}
```

**My questions are:**

1. How can I properly load websites such as the BBC?
2. How can I prepare my app to load any URL without needing a huge list
   of exceptions?
3. The app works fine if I set NSAppTransportSecurity.NSAllowsArbitraryLoads to YES, but I dont like that at all.
   What alternative to that do I have for the sake of Security and App Store approval?

Answer (score 1):

After much trial and error, this is the formula that worked for me:

1. Do NOT replace http: for https: in the URL string
2. Add individual domain exceptions for each domain you want to
   support. My app requires to display only 8 websites, so this
   combination works fine!:

> ```
> <key>bbc.co.uk</key>
>             <dict>
>                 <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
>                 <true/>
>                 <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
>                 <true/>
>                 <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
>                 <true/>
>                 <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
>                 <string>TLSv1.2</string>
>                 <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
>                 <false/>
>                 <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
>                 <true/>
>                 <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
>                 <string>TLSv1.2</string>
>                 <key>NSRequiresCertificateTransparency</key>
>                 <false/>
>             </dict>
> ```

Optional, the former also applies for this other approach, loading the URL on a SFSafariViewController. I will settle for this approach, which is quite reliable and even has back, next, refresh, and share buttons in a built in nav. bar. Here is the code:

```
    NSURL *wkURL = [NSURL URLWithString:wkURLstring];
    SFSafariViewController *safariVC = [[SFSafariViewController alloc] initWithURL:wkURL];
    [self.view.window.rootViewController presentViewController:safariVC animated:YES completion:^{
        NSLog(@"Full Safari Webview Launched");
    }];
```

Answer (score 0):

A more robust way to do this would be using the WKNavigationDelegate and in your case evaluate the URL. To handle with a huge list (without no more knowledge about that list) I would do a regular expression evaluation to perform based on it. Also you could create a redirection policy based on your needs.

For instance:

```
class WebNavigationHandler: NSObject, WKNavigationDelegate {

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Swift.Void) {

        //Based on the navigation action decide what to do.
        if canINavigate {
            decisionHandler(.allow)
        } else {
            decisionHandler(.cancel)
        }
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationResponse: WKNavigationResponse, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationResponsePolicy) -> Swift.Void) {

        // Base on the navigationResponse

        if canINavigate {
            decisionHandler(.allow)
        } else {
            decisionHandler(.cancel)
        }
    }

}

let webview = WKWebView()
webview.navigationDelegate = WebNavigationHandler()
```

Hope it answer your question.

Comment: I will try that, thanks. By a big list, I mean: I can't anticipate to all possible URLs that can come in during runtime by setting them individually in the .plist file. I'll be back when I try your approach.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the `NSAllowArbitraryLoadsInWebContent` setting for `NSAppTransportSecurity`. See this Apple document: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html